# Spring oauth2 authorization code grant - Impossibile to reach /oauth/authorize

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to secure my rest api with authorization code flow, but i don't understand why i'm getting the message:

```
User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
```

I have a web part of the application with User and Admin access, and a REST api part with 2 different grants, on /api/** authorization code and on /oauth2/** with client_credentials.

The client_credential flow work, but the authorization code nope...

So, this is my Authorization Server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authManager);

    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

}
```

This is my resource server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

     @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

           http
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")
    .antMatchers("/oauth2/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/oauth2/**").authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic();
        }

     @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

     @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {

            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }
}
```

And finally, this is the general Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/registrationConfirm", "/resendRegistrationToken")
                .permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/edit/**", "/payment/**", "/plate/**", "/book/**", "/home", "/stop/**",
                        "/notification/**", "/include/**")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('PARK')").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('PARK')").antMatchers("/updatePassword")
                .hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")

                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
                .successHandler(customSuccessHandler).failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and().rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied").and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout=true").invalidateHttpSession(false).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return db;
    }

}
```

The user in the **oauth_client_details** table has ROLE_USER as authorities, client_id and client_secret are test/test

This is how I'm searching to get the Token with POSTMAN

[image: POSTMAN OAUTH2 Token request]

but i'm getting the exception

```
ERROR i.b.e.e.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler[66] - 500 Status Code org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
```

**EDIT** this is what i see when i push the Request Token button

[image: Response]

**EDIT**
Inspecting the logs i also found that in my Security Filter chain there is no sign of any filter of Oauth2... When making the request to get the Authorization token i see:

```
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[325] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-04-07 22:50:34 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy[310] - /oauth/authorize?client_id=test&scope=&state=7220832&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman
```

Comment: Are you seeing the login page when pressing 'Request Access Token' ?

Comment: No i'g grtting the 500 errori and the messale that i nerd ti be authenticated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is this part inside `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
```

Spring is not detecting your login page and thus you cannot be redirected to authenticate to it as a user.

The solution would be to change it to:

```
.and().formLogin()
```

You will then use Spring's default login page and the Authorization Code flow should work. After that works, you would need to debug as to why your login page at `'/'` is not being detected.

**EDIT:**

The real problem was that `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class` is a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class which was messing with the redirection issued in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. This was because it was catching the exception and throwing it to the front-end without allowing the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` to issue the redirection to the login page. Removing the use of `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class` solves the issue and the Auth code flow works correctly.

Comment: nothin changed... I should have 2 login entry point `loginPage("/")` for the web application and standard Spring login for Oauth authentication

Comment: if you specify `loginPage("/")` you will not be able to access the default login page by spring ... see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/guides/form.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page

Comment: tried to... but i continue to get `User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be ` when trying to access /oauth/authorize I can login on the standard spring login page for the web part of the app.... the problem is with the REST part of it

Comment: So after pressing 'Request Token', you login through the Spring generated page and then get the error?

Comment: no, when i press it, i don't get the login page, i added the image in the original question

Comment: Can you try not using the `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class? That looks like to be messing with the auth code flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141242/discussion-between-luke-bajada-and-besmart).